# Dojo MD5 hash not in base 16 notation

Tags: javascript, hash, dojo, md5

I would like to generate an MD5 hash in Dojo that will match my hash in Java, using `MessageDigest`.  I'm  looking to generate a base 16 md5 hash in Dojo.  How do you do this?

```
dojo.require("dojox.encoding.digests.MD5");
var d = dojox.encoding.digests.MD5("test");

//gives me CY9rzUYh03PK3k6DJie09g== 

//was hoping for 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

I'm not finding much documentation online about this.

Comment: That is exactly what you wanted, just in a different encoding. It's giving you the MD5 hash in Base 64. Here's a website that will allow you to convert from Base 64 to hex: http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php I would give more detail and a full answer with JavaScript examples, but i'm currently answering from my phone. So hopefully that's enough information to get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dojo MD5 method has a second parameter that accepts an **outputType**:

```
d = dojox.encoding.digests.MD5("test", dojox.encoding.digests.outputTypes.Hex);
```

The API docs are confusing.  You don't pass in an object, just the output type, which is just a constant integer.

Demo:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jumpnett/Vgpwb/).

References:
[API](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojox/encoding/digests/MD5),
[Guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/encoding/digests.html)

Answer (score 0):

that's Base64 encoding.  If you are willing to do the decoding on the Java side (to compare with the MessageDigest output), then you can use the [decodeBase64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64%28java.lang.String%29) method from Apache Commons codec to get a byte array, then compare the byte array output from MessageDigest

if you want to compare on the javascript side, I would instead use [encodeBase64String](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String%28byte%5B%5D%29) to encode the byte array coming out of MessageDigest, and compare the base64 strings on the JS side.